# How to comment and uncomment a code in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Commenting my code in Visual Studio 2017 using Crtl+K+C and sometimes it works, but don't know how to uncomment it back.

I tried to comment my code in Visual Studio 2017 using Crtl+K+C and sometimes it works, but don't know how to uncomment it back. Help Please

Comment: CTRL+K+C to comment and CTRL+K+U to uncomment. 

You can also do CTRL+K, CTRL+C to comment and CTRL+K, CTRL+U to uncomment

Comment: If you hover the cursor over an icon, e.g., the comment/uncomment icons, a pop-up will provide the shortcut keys

Comment: CTRL+K+/ to toggle line comment

Comment: @Sreeram S P May I know if you have got any chance to check answers below?

Answer (score 1):

You can comment out code with ctrl+k+c and uncomment the code using ctrl+k+u

Answer (score 0):

On Toolbar -> Edit -> Advanced ->   Comment Selection ,
Uncomment Selection.